# Failed to start Neo4j after successful upgrade

Tags: neo4j

I installed neo4j 3.0.3. I took 2.3.0-M02 database, enabled upgrade by setting uncommenting

```
dbms.allow_format_migration=true
```

and started server, but it fails with

```
2016-06-15 17:50:18.439+0000 INFO  Starting...
2016-06-15 17:50:18.874+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2016-06-15 17:50:19.027+0000 INFO  Starting upgrade of database
2016-06-15 17:50:19.046+0000 INFO  Migrating Indexes (1/3):
2016-06-15 17:50:19.049+0000 INFO    10% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.049+0000 INFO    20% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.049+0000 INFO    30% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.050+0000 INFO    40% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.050+0000 INFO    50% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.050+0000 INFO    60% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.050+0000 INFO    70% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.050+0000 INFO    80% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.050+0000 INFO    90% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.050+0000 INFO    100% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.051+0000 INFO  Migrating Legacy indexes (2/3):
2016-06-15 17:50:19.057+0000 INFO    10% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.058+0000 INFO    20% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.058+0000 INFO    30% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.058+0000 INFO    40% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.058+0000 INFO    50% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.058+0000 INFO    60% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.058+0000 INFO    70% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.058+0000 INFO    80% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.058+0000 INFO    90% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.059+0000 INFO    100% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.059+0000 INFO  Migrating Store files (3/3):
2016-06-15 17:50:19.067+0000 INFO    10% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.067+0000 INFO    20% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.067+0000 INFO    30% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.068+0000 INFO    40% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.068+0000 INFO    50% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.068+0000 INFO    60% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.068+0000 INFO    70% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.068+0000 INFO    80% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.068+0000 INFO    90% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.068+0000 INFO    100% completed
2016-06-15 17:50:19.091+0000 INFO  Successfully finished upgrade of database
2016-06-15 17:50:19.389+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3693c13' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3693c13' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3693c13' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:217)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:87)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:28)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3693c13' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:189)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, /home/pavel/devel/neo4j-community-3.0.3/data/databases/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$31(CommunityNeoServer.java:55)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer$$Lambda$43/1644443712.newGraphDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine@6ec66b58' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:503)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:99)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.InvalidRecordException: DynamicRecord[1869509480,used=false,(0),type=-1,data=byte[],start=true,next=-1] not in use
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.record.RecordLoad.verify(RecordLoad.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.verifyAfterNotRead(CommonAbstractStore.java:1229)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.readIntoRecord(CommonAbstractStore.java:1051)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.access$000(CommonAbstractStore.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore$1.next(CommonAbstractStore.java:1177)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore$1.next(CommonAbstractStore.java:1142)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.RecordCursor.getAll(RecordCursor.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.getRecords(CommonAbstractStore.java:1124)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.TokenStore.ensureHeavy(TokenStore.java:141)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.TokenStore.getStringFor(TokenStore.java:146)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.TokenStore.getTokens(TokenStore.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.start(RecordStorageEngine.java:415)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    ... 19 more
```

I tried to google this one up, but there not much to be found, except the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrades from milestones are usually not supported.

Can you check that the old store was ok with the consistency checker?

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/01/22/neo4j-backup-store-copy-and-consistency-check/

You could also try to use my store-copy tool on your store to copy over all non-affected records: https://github.com/jexp/store-utils/tree/30

Comment: I suppose the old store is OK, because its in production up and running with 100+ days uptime, recording and serving 4GB database. Do you think that upgrading to 2.3.0 and then to 3.0.3 might work ?